# facebook send button z-index? Strange issue

Tags: facebook, dotnetnuke, z-index, send, galleria

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this Facebook element to appear above the slideshow gallery below it.  I'm pretty sure it's not an overflow issue, and z-index on either element doesn't seem to have any effect.

The problem appears here: lovegrows.org/marykay

Any ideas?

Comment: That one sure is a pain, I spent a while trying to track it down but haven't had any luck so far. I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that it is in an IFrame, but can't get CSS to fix it with any of my testing

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little more digging. It looks like the Gallery script that you are using has z-indexes in there for 99990 and 99991 for a number of elements.

Here's what I see that I believe to be the culprit, though I could only think of editing the files to see if that resolves the issue, I don't know of any other way to test this out.

```
cssMap = {
                overlay:    'position:fixed;display:none;opacity:'+op.overlayOpacity+';filter:alpha(opacity='+(op.overlayOpacity*100)+
                            ');top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:'+op.overlayBackground+';z-index:99990',
                box:        'position:fixed;display:none;width:400px;height:400px;top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:-200px;margin-left:-200px;z-index:99991',
                shadow:     abs+'background:#000;width:100%;height:100%;',
                content:    abs+'background-color:#fff;top:10px;left:10px;right:10px;bottom:10px;overflow:hidden',
                info:       abs+'bottom:10px;left:10px;right:10px;color:#444;font:11px/13px arial,sans-serif;height:13px',
                close:      abs+'top:10px;right:10px;height:20px;width:20px;background:#fff;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;color:#444;font:16px/22px arial,sans-serif;z-index:99999',
                image:      abs+'top:10px;left:10px;right:10px;bottom:30px;overflow:hidden;display:block;',
                prevholder: abs+'width:50%;top:0;bottom:40px;cursor:pointer;',
                nextholder: abs+'width:50%;top:0;bottom:40px;right:-1px;cursor:pointer;',
                prev:       abs+'top:50%;margin-top:-20px;height:40px;width:30px;background:#fff;left:20px;display:none;text-align:center;color:#000;font:bold 16px/36px arial,sans-serif',
                next:       abs+'top:50%;margin-top:-20px;height:40px;width:30px;background:#fff;right:20px;left:auto;display:none;font:bold 16px/36px arial,sans-serif;text-align:center;color:#000',
                title:      'float:left',
                counter:    'float:right;margin-left:8px;'
            },
```